# Displaying frequency of a location in a dataframe onto a world map

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a column of information (location) from a dataframe that looks as such:

```
Location
---------
New York
Chicago
Miami
New York
Portland
Miami
```

Using Dash (Python Visualization Library) I'd like to show these locations on a world map, as well as their frequency, possibly via a hover-over attribute. For example, a New York data point would be represented on the map, as well as a frequency of 2 if hovered over.

Any ideas on how to implement this within the Dash framework?

Comment: I think this is not the right type of question for stack-overflow, but I'd go with a Folium-Map and integrate it into dash using an iFrame. [Here is a blog post explaning how](https://medium.com/@shachiakyaagba_41915/integrating-folium-with-dash-5338604e7c56)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scattermapbox](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/), [Dash Leaflet](https://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/) or [Folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) in an iframe as noted by Rudertier. Here is a small example using Dash Leaflet,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl
import geocoder

locations = ["New York", "Chicago", "Miami", "New York", "Portland", "Miami"]
# Create markers.
markers = [dl.Marker(title=locations.count(item), position=geocoder.osm(item).latlng) for item in list(set(locations))]
# Create app.
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(dl.Map([dl.TileLayer()] + markers, center=[39, -98], zoom=4),
                      style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Dash Leaflet.